# Placing form elements on new lines without <br>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a form to use for my work, I guess my question is more of a why does this happen.

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input type="radio" name="transport_method" >Delivery
   <input type="radio" name="transport_method">Store Pick-Up
   <input type="radio" name="transport_method" >Day Trip
</div>
```

my css class of "checkbox" looks like this

```
.checkbox {
   float: left;
   display: inline;
}
```

now my code at the next element

```
<div>First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</div><br><br><br>
```

I have to add 3 `<br>`'s to get the "First name:" to be on a new line. I started with only 2 radio buttons and then I only needed 2 `<br>`'s. Is there a way to format my css to not need any `<br>`'s?

I think I need the `<br>`'s (correct me if I'm wrong) due to the fact that html file is reading the radio buttons as new lines and displaying them on one line, therefore the `<br>`'s fix that issue, but I don't like using them nor do I think it is semantically correct.

Comment: Well first of all...  you can't have float: left; display: inline;....  that doesn't even make sense.  Its one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

## Let's start with a nicely marked up form

### The form elements

- The radio buttons can be wrapped in a [`<fieldset>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)
- The labels can all be marked up with [`<label>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). The [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Using_the_.22for.22_attribute) links to its input via the matching [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). One benefit of this is that users can click/touch on the label.

That gives us this:

```
<form>
  <fieldset class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="delivery">
    <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>

    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="pick-up">
    <label for="pick-up">Store Pick-Up</label>

    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="day-trip">
    <label for="day-trip">Day Trip</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="names">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">

    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Bring each text input onto a new line

The default display value for inputs is `display: inline` which brings them all onto one line. Use `display: block` on text inputs to knock them down:

```
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
}
```

We want the radio buttons to remain on the one line, so they can be left at their default `display: inline`. [More information on `display`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

### Full example

Bring it all together with a little bit more CSS:

```css
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
label,
input[type=radio] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
form {
  background: #FFF9C4;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="delivery">
    <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="pick-up">
    <label for="pick-up">Store Pick-Up</label>
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" id="day-trip">
    <label for="day-trip">Day Trip</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="names">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">

    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1axqn595/1/)**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method">Delivery
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method">Store Pick-Up
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method">Day Trip</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div>First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
</div>
```

`.clear{clear:both}` instead of `<br/>`

**EDIT:** If you dont want to create new class you can use like this too :

**[Updated dmo](https://jsfiddle.net/1axqn595/3/)**

```
.checkbox::after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: I use an external css would I need to create a clear class and call it on the div I have my radio buttons in? I suppose I could just add it to my "checkbox class" which should be renamed anyway.

Comment: I updated my answer.. you are using float:left for checkbox, so you need to clear that to show next field in new line

Comment: you cant use float:left and clear for same div, both do different action.. so use clear after your float like I used or you can use it as :after pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" >Delivery
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method">Store Pick-Up
    <input type="radio" name="transport_method" >Day Trip
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>     
<div>
  First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

in css

```
.clear{
clear:both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
.checkbox{display:block}
```

And if you mean to have those checbox inputs floated to left, then use

```
.checkbox input{display:inline-block}
```

And there you go, no floats, no `br` tags, nothing weird

Answer (score 0):

Using the new class amit made

> use .clear{clear:both} instead of

on the following element, in my case

```
<div >First name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</div>
```

turned into

```
<div class="clear">First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
</div>
```